# Setting up a variable with Cell Content with Range(Cells(),Cells()) Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for reading this anyway. Here's my problem: I have a list of courses on a sheet and i'm using them as reference to count how many times this courses will appear in one year. But i can't set my variable to get one of this courses at a time. Here's the code:

```
lr = ws.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

ReDim x(lr - 1)
For i = 1 To (lr - 1)
    k = ws.Range(Cells(1 + i, 1), Cells(1 + i, 1)).Text
        For Each sheets In wb.sheets
            With sheets.Range("A1:J86")
                Set rng = .Find(k, sheets.Cells(1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False)
                    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                        v = v + 1
                    End If
            End With
        Next sheets
    x(i) = (v - 1)
    v = 0
Next
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: how about iterating over the range with For Each instead of a for i loop? that way you can: `For Each currCell in myRange` and then `currCell.Value` will give you the course value\text and you can use countif on the range to check how many times this value appers in it, or something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Range(Cells(), Cells())` for only one cell:

```
k = ws.Cells(1 + i, 1).Text
```

will suffice.